# MVVMLight EventToCommand causing memory Leak

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks, mvvm-light

HI

I got this xaml with my EventToCommand connected to MVVM, the problem with this code is that after navigating away from the page that hold it always staying in memory.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10" 
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding Foo, Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FooChangeCommand}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Show Al" />               
            <ComboBoxItem Content="..." /> 
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Take a look at their code, are they using weak references? if not, do you think that they need to? I am guessing that something cuases a circular reference problem.

Comment: I re-tagged it with the mvvm-light tag - The MVVM Light creator, and many experts on the project follow the tag.  Hopefully one of them will be able to address this.

Comment: I haven't got any circular references, but I have to find the time to repro and send it to Mr MVVM Light

Answer (score 6):

2 years latter and I have exactly the same problem.

I've solved using `i:InvokeCommandAction` instead of `cmd:EventToCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7512

As the above link is dead:

1. Go to https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvvmlight
2. Switch from `home` to `issues`
3. Search within page for "EventToCommand Memory Leak (Windows Phone 7 SP1 Toolkit)"

The comments on the issue indicate that https://atomaras.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/solving-mvvmlights-eventtocommand-memory-leak-wp7/ may provide a deeper analysis and a soulution to the problem.

Comment: link is broken, project is now http://www.mvvmlight.net/ but there I haven't found anything related

Comment: Updated the post. The information is still on CodePlex but sadly not linkable.